# Excel VBA SUM Formula Displaying in Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following routine called from a procedure

```
Sub DoTotals()

  With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
    .Formula = "=SUM(F2:" & .Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
  End With

End Sub
```

The result displayed in the cell is not the result of the summation, but 
`=SUM(F$1:$F2)`

I've used the same routine in other Excel docs and it properly returned the sum - not in this one, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell may have been formatted to Text.......try:

```
Sub DoTotals()
With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
    .Clear
    .Formula = "=SUM(F2:" & .Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT #1**:

Perhaps the Window is in the wrong display mode:

```
Sub DoTotals()
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)(2, 1)
        .Clear
        .Formula = "=SUM(F2:" & .Offset(-1, 0).Address & ")"
    End With
        ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried the suggestion - still getting the formula displayed... Thanks!

Comment: If at first we don't succeed, see **Edit#1**